# Can you change the epoch on a system?

Tags: linux, windows, epoch

Linux, Unix and derivatives use UNIX epoch whereas Windows uses a different epoch.

Is it possible to change the epoch used by the system? So that an operation like getting the current timestamp on that system would return number of milliseconds since that particular epoch?

If it is possible(no matter how complex), whats the best way to query the system to identify the epoch?

Comment: Why would you want to change the Epoch? It is is just a useful *convention*. Your software wants to compute time....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch An example would be to create a UUID generator for a private distributed system.I was reading snowflake's implementation in a systems design book where they used a custom epoch which led me to this question

Answer (score 2):

> Can you change the epoch on a system?

No, but you could use portable frameworks like [Glib](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/). And you could download then study the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (for time related functions).

You could also document and define your own convention, e.g. using preprocessor tricks (or [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/))

For example, decide and document your time getting function return a `double` counting seconds from january 1st, 2020.

Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and preprocessor (e.g. [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)) and of your operating system (for Linux, [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [clock_gettime(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)...)

Windows of course has a [different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/how-the-windows-time-service-works), but documented, API.

PS. You could also *generate* some C code using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or (in 2022) [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) (about which you could contact me by email `basile@starynkevitch.net`)

NB. The evil is in the details. Be aware of [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). You may want to use some [NTPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) service, if your computer is connected to the Internet.

Comment: What have "portable frameworks like glib"  got to do with changing a systems epoch?   What has GPP or RefPerSys got to do with changing a systems epoch?   Oh, and what have leap seconds or NTP to do with changing a systems epoch?

Comment: Glib is usable on several OSes and provide OS independent wrappers related to time. And if you decide to reimplemented these, you'll need a lot of work. I recommend using NTP service. Otherwise, computing time is difficult (because of leap seconds)

Comment: If you have to rewrite an entire library related to time, budget months of work.